# Cascading combobox in XAML file

Tags: wpf, data-binding

```
 <ComboBox Name="comboBox1"  Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Right" SelectedIndex="0"  Margin="0,33,142,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" >
        <ComboBoxItem Name="cb1" Cotent= "AA"/> 
        <ComboBoxItem Name="cb2" Content="BB"/>
 </ComboBox>



 <ComboBox  Name="comboBox2" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Right" SelectedIndex="0"  Margin="0,33,142,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" >
        <ComboBoxItem Content ="a"/> 
        <ComboBoxItem Content="b"/>
        <ComboBoxItem Content="c"/>
    </ComboBox>

<ComboBox Name="comboBox3" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Right" SelectedIndex="0"  Margin="0,33,142,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" >
        <ComboBoxItem Content ="d"/> 
        <ComboBoxItem Content="e"/>
        <ComboBoxItem Content="f"/>
    </ComboBox>
```

I want combobox2 items if i select **cb1** and combobox3 items if select **cb2**.
how to bind it in xaml.

Comment: Please explain a but more in context of wanting the items of combo boxes ? where do you want those and what do you want to do with those ?

Comment: @Umair i just want cascade combobox using xaml.

Comment: Please explain what do you have in mind in meaning for cascading combo boxes ?

Comment: Is there a reason why you don't want to add content to the second combobox dynamically depending on the selection of the first combo box via code in the code behind file?